# How to git commit backwards?

Tags: git

1. Suppose that I commit a file with contents `How is it possible to git commits backwards?`. Let's call this commit `final`.
2. I then change the file contents to `How to git commit backwards?`. Let's call this commit `before`.
3. I then change the file contents to `Foo bar`. Let's call this commit `first`.

How can I have the commits to be ordered `first --> before --> final`? (reverse of usual order)

I do not care about the hash changing each time.

I do not want to start with nothing and then commit in the usual way. Getting changes for committing backwards is easier.

The closest I can think of is:

1. do commits in order above
2. export patches
3. `git apply --reverse` patches

Comment: Creative interactive rebasing can do this. However, unless you understand how Git (and especially conflicts, because you’ll get lot’s of ’em) works, I simply do not think this is feasible.

Comment: I have to question purpose?  Things like this are a nightmare for the engineers responsible for the git tree.  Yes, you can trick git into shoving stuff where it shouldn't belong but it is a bad idea.  Also.. `Let's call this commit final` .. you mean the message that goes with the commit?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas no, I mean file contents. It would usually be code. I will also be sole developer to repo so it does not matter.